# Android : Why Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY shows Google Photos

Tags: android, android-gallery

What I'm trying to do in my application is to let the user choose a picture from his phone's gallery(Don't want to [get gallery images only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585303/android-get-only-image-from-gallery) but also allowing a user to choose their app of choice). The code I'm using is as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
```

As per [Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620794/intent-extra-local-only-doesnt-work)

> **EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY** only tells the receiving app that it should return
>   only data that is present.

After adding `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);` in above code,it hide **google drive app** and **picasa app** but still shows **google photos**(those photos are not in my device.)

Also I tried [Android image picker for local files only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080109/android-image-picker-for-local-files-only) but It hide all the apps having remote images excluding google photos.

Note : All the image paths are correct as I did [Android Gallery on KitKat returns different Uri for Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20559418/991085) (thanks to @Paul Burke)  but I don't want to pick internet/remote images.

So my question **Is there any way to hide google photos app while pick an image from local device only.** or Is google photos is part of `Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY`

Answer (score 15):

> EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY only tells the receiving app that it **should** return
> only data that is present.

Google+ Photos stores both local and remote pictures and because of that is registered for that intent with that extra. However apparently it ignores wherever calling intent has `EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY` set to true.

You could try removing G+ Photos from list manually (however this seems a bit hacky):

```
List<Intent> targets = new ArrayList<Intent>();
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
List<ResolveInfo> candidates = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

for (ResolveInfo candidate : candidates) {
  String packageName = candidate.activityInfo.packageName;
  if (!packageName.equals("com.google.android.apps.photos") && !packageName.equals("com.google.android.apps.plus") && !packageName.equals("com.android.documentsui")) {
      Intent iWantThis = new Intent();
      iWantThis.setType("image/*");
      iWantThis.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
      iWantThis.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
      iWantThis.setPackage(packageName);
      targets.add(iWantThis);
    }
}
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(targets.remove(0), "Select Picture");
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targets.toArray(new Parcelable[targets.size()]));
startActivityForResult(chooser, 1);
```

Few words of explanation: `targets.remove(0)` will remove and return first Intent from `targets` list, so the chooser will consist only of one application. Then with `Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS` we add the rest.

The code snippet is modified version from this [link](https://rogerkeays.com/how-to-remove-the-facebook-android-sharing-intent).

Please remember to check all conditions like if there is at least one app available and so on.

Comment: Thanks to answer,but now it shows all the targets apps in chooser dialog and in that dialog  it show one options named as **document** which shows all the apps again,i.e. **google photos** is again displayed after  **document** is selected.

Comment: I get your new problem now - **Documents** is another application (I suppose it was added in 4.4). Since you cannot modify another applications, just exclude it from the list, like we did before with G+. I updated the code.

Comment: Thanks to reply,but if in kitkat and newer versions local images and downloads folder is under **Documents**,then if Documents is not shown then how can I show local Images if there is no file explorer installed in user device.And more is there any way to show local device images i.e. user may pick image from google photos having local also.

Comment: Giving all your requirements the only way to accomplish what you want is to implement your own Pictures Picker.

Comment: Yes you are right that will be the final step but it is only probelm with google photos rest are fine (like picasa).