# How to restrict Google drive option from not appearing while selecting file or image in Android below API level 19?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am newbie in Android and I have a requirement for selecting files on devices below API level 19.

I have tried

```
private void chooseFile() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
             intent.setType("application/pdf|file");
        } else {
             intent.setType("image/*|application/pdf");
        }
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Now I do not want Google drive to appear as an option and I want file-manager as an option. I want to do this with intents.

Can any one suggest how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
```

Comment: is there any way to hide dropbox as well

Comment: Dropbox can be used to store local files so no. But using this tag should only allow the user to choose files which are synced locally.

Comment: but the above solution is not working for api level 16 devices ....google drive option is still there

Comment: The above Extra was added in API 11. Here is a solution to manually remove specific apps from the share list, but it's pretty hacky. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27780510/106941

Comment: For me too, not working in API level 21. Any solution for the same ?

Answer (score 5):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
 //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
 intent.setType("application/pdf");
 startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

This will work for me to avoid gdrive from chooser

Comment: But it only allows to choose PDF files what about rest?

Comment: change setType value like below
intent.setType("image/*|application/pdf|audio/*");
@ShylendraMadda

Comment: Yeah, but how it answers the OP question? `How to restrict Google drive option from not appearing while selecting file or image in Android below API level 19?`