# exclude the google drive option in browsing files through intent in android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, filechooser

this is a asked question but i did not solve it using that solution. 
Here is my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getDownloadCacheDirectory().getPath().toString());
intent.setDataAndType(uri,"*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
try {
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "SELECT FILE"), commonUtilities.FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
}
```

Still Google drive options is there. I just want  not to display the google drive option.

How can i get that , Help me out. Thank in adv

Comment: `Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY` What should that do?

Comment: Which solution? Provide a link if you refer to simething.

Comment: I use `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);` from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310167/how-to-restrict-google-drive-option-from-not-appearing-while-selecting-file-or-i] which did not work

Comment: can you give any solution?

Answer (score 2):

> I just want not to display the google drive option.

What *you* want is not important. What your *users* want is important. Some of your users may want to get content from Google Drive, file servers on the local network, and other places that they have configured on their device that support `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

Beyond that, in general, you cannot control what options `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` provides to users.

So, if you do not want Google Drive to appear as an option, do not use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` (or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, etc.). Do something else, such as integrate a [file-picker library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created).

Answer (score 0):

```
  Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, 
    getString(R.string.label_select_video)), REQUEST_VIDEO_TRIMMER);
```

try this is working for me.